# What is wall crossing?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory

I know that it must have something to do with (gauge?) theories with N=2 supersymmetry, BPS states and even black holes, but most papers on the subject are too technical for me. So what is wall crossing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wall crossing is any discontinuous change of an integer (or at least rational) quantity - or, more generally, any qualitative change of the spectrum etc. - that occurs when one moves to the opposite side from a "wall" in a moduli space or parameter space.

A would-be index may suddenly change discontinuously.

The wall - a codimension one locus in the parameter space - is then referred to as the "wall of marginal stability". One one side, an object may be stable while it is unstable on the other side. It is typically unstable because a decay suddenly becomes plausible because the hypothetical decay product get light enough, if you wish.

The objects are typically BPS objects on the stable side and they can also be BPS black holes or any other BPS objects.

To see objects that may be exactly stable, BPS, but that are also sufficiently diverse, $N=2$ supersymmetry or eight supercharges is an ideal number of supercharges. That's why those considerations played an important role in the Seiberg-Witten insights about $N=2$ gauge theories, among related situations.

Paul Aspinwall liked to say that 8 supercharges is the optimum number for nice physics. Only Nature didn't manage to choose the number 8 for supercharges, but that's not Aspinwall's fault.

Comment: What about the `other side' of the wall, i.e. must the decay products be still BPS ? Also, how should we consider WMS decay for Seiberg-Witten case ? I'd say that any dyon (other than charge with (1,-1)) can decay into a monopole (1,0) and a dyon (1,-1) at WMS where these constituents get massless, is it correct ? Are these (massless) constituents also BPS then ? Also would not this violate mass (energy) conservation because initially we have some non-zero total mass and finally we have a zero mass ? Lastly, isn't this process in contradiction with the stability condition of BPS states ?

Comment: On the other side of the wall, the object is unstable. It means that its mass is strictly greater than the (any) BPS bound. You can never violate the BPS bound which is an easily and reliably provable mathematical inequality! Also, none of the objects we are talking about here have zero mass. Finally, when a non-BPS object decay, the decay products may be BPS objects but it's just a coincidence. They may preserve SUSY but each decay product preserves different supercharges. In general, non-BPS objects may (and often do) appear among decay products of a non-BPS initial state.